# Help with VLAN Configuration between 2 MikroTik CRS125-24G Devices

Tags: vlan, sonicwall

I have a SonicWALL with X0=`10.11.10.0/24` and X2=`192.168.11.0/24`. The downstairs MikroTik ports 1-19 are in `192.168.11.0/24`, and ports 21-24 are in `10.11.10.0/24` I am assuming port 20 will be my trunk port to the 2nd MikroTik upstairs. on the 2nd MikroTik, I want port 1 to be the trunk, with Ports 2-20 on `192.168.11.0/24`, and ports 21-24 on `10.11.10.0/24`.

The reason I am trying to do it this way is that this is a business in an older home, and I only have one Category-5E cable that is between my downstairs MikroTik and the upstairs MikroTik.

Is this doable, and if so, can someone help me out on the configurations, as I am new to the VLAN game?

Comment: This is for a business just inside a old home. Sorry should have clarified that. They are separate VPN Networks from secondary locations that need to stay divorced for HIPAA compliance.

Comment: Have you looked at this:http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/VLAN?

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin! I will look that over closer and see if I can decipher it. Will also watch this for some possibly more "real world" examples or help.

Comment: Please do not [cross post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/244349) the same question on  multiple sites. Choose whichever site you think is most appropriate and post there. If the question doesn't get enough attention you can use the bounty system, flag the post for a moderator to migrate (if there is content worth saving) or delete/repost on the new site (if there are no comments/answers worth saving). [For reference](http://superuser.com/questions/1059370/vlan-between-2-mikrotiks).

Answer (score 1):

As he is using CRS switches correct links would be:

- [CRS examples](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:CRS_examples)
- [CRS features](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:CRS_features)

Basically, what I would do is reset the switch and make all ports part of the same switch with ether1 being the master port. Then I would specify VLAN for separation and proper tagging for trunk ports. This way you would have full speed switching.

Generic VLAN stuff on Mikrotik is CPU bound so while it would work on CRS it would not be very fast.